# Is there a way to get a blob's ContentType in Azure.Storage.Blobs?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm switching to the newer Azure.Storage.Blobs and want to serve up a blob as a file via API to a client.

In the now-deprecated Microsoft.Azure.Storage and Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, I was able to do it like this:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;

    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("foo");
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobId);
    var bar = blob.Properties.ContentType;
```

Now that I'm in Azure.Storage.Blobs, the setup looks the same, but I'm missing the punchline:

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(storageConnectionString, containerName);
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("foo");
```

There's no analogous blockblob in the newer library, I can read the blobClient into a stream, but where do I get its content type without resorting to older libraries?

I'm hoping to be able to hit a FileResult, returning something that matches this signature:

```
File(Stream fileStream, string contentType, string fileName);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch blob’s properties using [GetBlobProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.getproperties?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_GetProperties_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) and that will give you the content type of the blob. Something like (untested code):

```
var getBlobPropertiesResult = blobClient.GetProperties();
var contentType = getBlobPropertiesResult.Value.ContentType;
```

Comment: This is kicking an error for me - Response<BlobProperties> does not contain a definition for 'ContentType'. If I should add a reference, which one should I look at?

Comment: Sorry about that. I’m not in front of a computer right now but can you try blobProperties.Value.ContentType.?

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I didn't do that. I need a coffee. Or a nap, or both. Thanks so much

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you :). Updated my answer as well.